# File upload error on mac browser not PC browser

Tags: browser

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+. at
System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) at
System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format) at
System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename) at
Content.btnAddImage_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
d:\inetpub\vhosts\rhinoreview.com\httpdocs\Content.ascx.cs:line 543
```

This process works perfect on any browser on a PC but does not work at all on any browser on a mac osx. A little lost on this one....

Comment: That's not really enough info to go on.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Are you using the same image file when testing the upload on both MAC and PC? The most common cause that I have seen for the "generic error occurred in GDI+" is when you're trying to save a bitmap that has already been disposed....

Comment: You need to give more information for us to be able to help. My guess would be: From a windows browser you're uploading a valid image: From the mac browser you're uploading a broken image, or one that .NET can't read...

Comment: What are the values of the parameters that you are passing?

Answer (score 1):

Nitpicking: it looks more like a download problem (from server to client) than an upload one (client sending a file to server).

Even more nitpicking: for me, PC means just Personal Computer. So computing running Mac OS or Linux or BSD or BeOS are just PC. I guess you mean PCs running Windows.

Wild guess, to add some value to this message: do you send the right headers along with the image?
It is hard to debug from the little info you provide (no code, no indication of language (C# likely) in the tags, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess, but it might be related to file extensions (it seems like GDI+ is failing when trying to convert the uploaded image to something it understands). I don't think Mac OS X needs them; are you uploading an image that doesn't have a file extension?